# Regular expression using python to extract the latitude and longitude

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract the lat long which is in the below format using regex in python.

(-17.23465,4.6883)

I need some one to guide me on this as I'm new to this topic.

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with something like  `lat, long = (-17.23465,4.6883)` ?

Comment: No, I have the lat long in the format as I mentioned.

Comment: ...and that format is a tuple. Unless it's not, and it's supposed to be a string.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest regular expression to do what you want is `\(([^,]*),([^\)]*)\)`.

The most clear regex solution is:

```
> import re
> match = re.match('^\((?P<lat>-?\d*(.\d+)),(?P<long>-?\d*(.\d+))\)$',
                   '(-17,23465,4.6883)')
> float(match.group('lat'))
-17.23465
> float(match.group('long'))
4.6883
```

The simplest solution using just string operations is:

```
> latlong = '(-17,23465,4.6883)'
> lat, long = [float(x) for x in latlong[1:-1].split(',')]
```

To learn more about regular expressions in practice, use [Online regex tester](https://regex101.com/) (set *python* flavor). To learn much more about regular expressions in Python read [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the latitude and longitude separately, and the value you are providing is a string, you could do:

```
val = '(-17.23465,4.6883)'
val = val.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').split(',')

lat = val[0]
lon = val[1]
```

**Output:**

> lat: -17.23465
>
> lon: 4.6883

Comment: Did you mean for `val` to be a string? Because this code raises a `AttributeError`: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Comment: @ChristianDean Yes, good call. I updated my answer. Thank you for pointing that out!